Problema para cargar los estilos css y javascript en Git-Hub Page
Tengo una consulta subi mi página a github pages y no me carga los ccs y javascript. Me sale unicamente el esqueleto en html
https://github.com/Ignacioaj131982/encuentroxrosario.github.io/settings/pages
https://ignacioaj131982.github.io/encuentroxrosario.github.io/

¿Similar?

Las rutas están mal

Como deberia ser?

Prueba a cambiarlas, modificando lo mínimo. Según entiendo tu página funciona, hasta que la cargas a github, entonces necesita reconocer bien los links. Haz que inicien con "/CSS/..." como lo sugiere la otra publicación. Incluso para testear varios, puedes dejar unos de la forma normal, otros de la forma cambiada, y probar con otros. Asegurate que los directorios se mantengan correctos en github,

@Excorpion gracias voy a probar, si la página funciona en vscode!!

Si el CSS, el JavaScript y las imágenes no son reconocidos, puede ser que la configuración no haya sido definida.
En la carpeta del repositorio, entra en la configuración del proyecto. (Settings)

Corrige y renombra el patrón de las páginas. El repositorio será el nombre de usuario seguido por github.io. {myuser}.github.io y publicado como público.
rename
Ignacioaj131982.github.io


En las opciones laterales en Pages

Intente verificar las configuraciones en el repositorio de la página, colocando el patrón correcto. Build and deployment está marcado en el Branch.
Si el Branch está como /root

De esta forma, al referenciar en el HTML /pasta_css/style.css, el "/" se considerará como la raíz del proyecto y después de la raíz estarán las carpetas de los archivos y serán reconocidos.
